# How to determine whether the load or charger is connected to batteries so that BMS can decide which MOSFET (charge and discharge) should be driven?

Tags: mosfet, battery-charging, bms

I am building a simple BMS circuit and don't know how to design the circuit that determines if load or charger is currently connected and decides which MOSFET should be driven.

Comment: When you refer to "open" in your title, what do you mean <-- it seems to contradict your test which kind of implies the same state as when "mosfet should be driven". Open in EE means open-circuit i.e. not activated and non conducting btw.

Comment: My bad, edited. I don't think it's the place to test my grammar. You understood what I asked exactly so instead of English grammar lesson you could help me out

Comment: A current shunt?

Comment: Just look for BMS protection circuits

Comment: No, I didn't understand the contradiction in your question and, because of that, I asked you about it. Many newbies use the hydraulic term "open" to imply an activated path. And maybe you were mistakenly doing the same. So, please don't presume to know my mind when I made the comment. I think I've explained myself enough now.